# retrieve all the hyperlinks from html file using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to retrieve all the hyperlinks present in current html page using jquery. How can i use regular expressions to do that? Also can i use collections in javascript to store all the hrefs in the list?

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple each-loop:

```
// For each <a href=""> tag...
$('a').each(function(){
    // Get the url
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    // alert it or do sth with it
    alert( href ); 
})
```

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Comment: Use `$(html_tring_here).find('a').each(...`

Comment: Might want to use `.filter()` rather than `.find()` because `.find()` won't match any top-level elements.

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery `$('a')` will do it for you

Iterating through all the anchor elements

```
var hrefArr = [];
$('a').each(function(){
  //hrefArr.push($(this).attr('href')); 
  hrefArr.push(this.href); // this would be bit faster then the statement above it
});
```

Edit on comment by OP, Finding the anchor tags in string contain html

```
str = "<div><a href='local1'></a><a href='local2'></a></div>"
var hrefArr = [];
$(str).filter('a').each(function(){
    hrefArr.push(this.href); 
});​
```

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Comment: replace $('a') with $(str).find('a') where str contains the text

Comment: Might want to use `.filter()` rather than `.find()` because `.find()` won't match any top-level elements in the string. (Your example string would of course work with `.find()` since you assumed a div as a container.)

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn for your suggestion, changed to filter.

Answer (score 0):

All anchors would be quite easy

```
$("a").each(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr("href") );
})
```

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the hyperlinks on the page

```
$('a')
```

And this will give you collection of hrefs on the hpyerlinks

```
var hrefs = new Array();
$('a').each(function() {
    hrefs.push(this.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: That second example will return the `href` attribute of the _first_ anchor tag, not a collection.

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Answer (score 0):

If by "collections in javascript" you mean an array then you can do this:

```
var hrefs = [];
$("a").each(function() {
    hrefs.push(this.href);
});
// hrefs array now contains all the hrefs
```

Within the `.each()` callback function `this.href` will likely return the full url that would be followed if you click the link, that is `href="test.htm"` would be returned as `http://yourdomain/test.htm`. If you want just the bit literally in the attribute use `$(this).attr("href")`.

You wouldn't use a regex to do that type of processing.

Comment: i used yql to retrieve html of a link but i need to get href from that result which was returned by the yql. Instead of this.href can i pass the html string to it?

Comment: Can you pass the html string to _what_? I'm not very familiar with yql, but if that's what you're using why didn't you say so in your question? You asked for a jQuery solution. If we assume your yql returns the html into a string `str` then you could do `$(str).filter("a").each(...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var link = "";
$("a").each(function() {
    link += $(this).attr("href"); 
});
alert(link);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that concatenating all the hrefs together without any spaces or commas is going to help.